# Resultado de consulta linq a objeto

Tags: c#, linq, conversión-de-tipos

estoy recuperando los datos de una tienda online "woocommerce", que luego filtro con una consulta en linq.
Me interesaria recojer el resultado de esta consulta en un objeto.

```
        private void btLinies_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        List<Order> loOrders = new List<Order>();
        string id = comboBox1.SelectedItem.ToString();
        loOrders = Task.Run(() => rec.Order.GetAll()).Result;
        Order comanda = loOrders.Select(x => x.id.Equals(id));

    }
```

Pero esto me genera errores de conversion que no se como solucionar:

> (Extension) ***Select (Func selector) I sobrecarga)
>   No se puede convertir implicitamente el tipo en 'WooCommerceNET.WooCommerce.v3.Order'. Ya existe una
>   conversiön explicita (compruebe si Ie falta una conversiön)***

¿ Me pueden ayudar por favor ?
Gracias.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Lo que te esta ocurriendo es que linq cuando tu haces las consultas retornan mas de un resultado es decir te retorna una lista de objetos si tu aplicas `.FirstOrDefault()` te va a retornar el primer objeto que encuentre o un null (si mal no recuerdo) 
Para los dos casos puedes aplicar esto

```
List<Order> comanda = loOrders.Where(x => x.id.Equals(id)).FirstOrDefault();
//y esto
List<Customer> cli = from comanda in loOrders
                      join
                       client in loClient on
                       comanda.customer_id equals client.id
                      select client;
```

Por otro lado añado una pequeña correccion

```
Order comanda = loOrders.Where(x => x.id.Equals(id)).Select(x=> x.id).FirstOrDefault();
//es mas correcto esto ya que se realiza menor carga
Order comanda = loOrders.FirstOrDefault(x => x.id.Equals(id)).Select(x=> x.id);
```

Comment: Cierto, resuelto!

Comment: puedes ponerlo como resuelto para que mas personas si tienen dudas lo puedan leer y encuentren la solución

Comment: ¿Es suficiente marcando tu respuesta como respuesta aceptada?

Answer (score 0):

intenta esto.

```
Order comanda = loOrders.Where(x => x.id.Equals(id)).FirstOrDefault();
```

si deseas solo el campo de id seria algo asi.

```
Order comanda = loOrders.Where(x => x.id.Equals(id)).Select(x=> x.id).FirstOrDefault();
```